# Bridging wan interface using macvtap - no connection to host

Tags: ubuntu, bridge, libvirt, qemu, bridged-adapter

So I have an ubuntu server with 1 WAN interface with a public ip address. I would like to bridge this interface so that the qemu guest vm will use the same interface.

I used the guide in
https://ahelpme.com/linux/howto-do-qemu-full-virtualization-with-macvtap-networking/

Everything works but I suspect that some ip conflict exists as I loose my ssh connection to the host after a few seconds of this setup.

Any idea onhow to fix this ?
I have oy 1 public ip address

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If using macvtap it is pretty common to end up with guests being able to reach the WAN, but not reach the immediate host. I won't repeat the details here, just point to this page which describes the problem and possible solutions:

https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/TroubleshootMacvtapHostFail

Comment: Thank u, but I do not mind that the guest cannot talk with host. As far as I am concerned, I would like the guest to be bridged to wan and that wan clients can talk to the guest.

Comment: Just to clarify @DanielB, I meant connection to host from wan